# Visual Studio Setup and Deployment - Changing installation for Single User and All Users

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have a Visual C++ Setup which I created using Visual Studio Setup Wizard. I'm trying to give the user option of **selecting to install for himself only or everyone**. How do I do this??
Even though I can select a radio button saying Install for All Users at install time, it did not work. I need this to work in Windows 7. I have some **files(Some Add-in files for MS Excel, .XLAM) to be copied and a DLL which is automatically registered so those should happen for everyone as well.** IS there a specific folder in the machine that I should copy the .XLAM files for them to be available for all users??

Thank You!